# ios background white gradiant

Tags: ios, background

I have a View in Xcode and I am developing for IOS. I want to set background of my view same as that of this pictures alert background. I have tried setting alpha but I am unable to produce same look. How to achieve this?

---

[image: this]

Comment: First try to do some google search. For now go through this -> https://www.raywenderlich.com/167-uivisualeffectview-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert "Visual Effect with Blur" as background of your view.

---

[image: this]